# Why do process blocks correctly return a hashtable, instead of an array of hashtables?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I am trying to sort some REST API responses and extract data from them, and found [this helpful](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/10847711/11472732) answer on how to end up with a hashtable at the end.

```
$res= (Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink) | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Property id, filename | ForEach-Object -begin {$h=@{}} -process {$h[$_.filename] = $_.id} -end {$h}
```

Great, so I thought I'd shorten it a bit by getting rid of the begin/process/end blocks like so:

```
$res = (Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink) | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Property id, filename | ForEach-Object { $h=@{}; $h[$_.filename] = $_.id; $h }
```

All good, I should now be able to reference each item by it's key value using square brackets, but that doesn't work, only referencing by dot notation.

So I went searching and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795866/11472732), which turned out to be correct:

```
$res.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

But, even changing from the generic hashtable constructor to using the `.Add()` method didn't help:

```
$res = (Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink) | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Property id, filename | ForEach-Object { $h=@{}; $h.add($_.filename, $_.id); $h }

$res.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

I add the process blocks back in:

```
$res = (Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "$foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink) | ForEach-Object { $_ } | Select-Object -Property id, filename | ForEach-Object -begin {$h=@{}} -process {$h[$_.filename] = $_.id} -end {$h}

$res.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
```

And it's all working as expected.

So I'd like to know, if possible, what exactly is happening when I use the process blocks as opposed to just making 'fake' multi-line functions in the pipeline?

And if anyone cares, I actually ended up avoiding the above issue completely by using `Group-Object` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49036660/11472732).

Comment: You might want to read [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2) emulates how [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) work in the [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3). The reason why the first and last snippets work as expected, returning a hashtable is because `-Begin` and `-End` not because of `-Process` which executes by default and is a mandatory parameter. If you don't use `-Begin` you would simply be creating and outputting a new hashtable per input object.

- Using `ForEach-Object`

```
0..10 | ForEach-Object -Begin {
    "executes only once, before the first input object is processed"
} -Process {
    "processes each input object: $_"
} -End {
    "executes only once, after the last input object is processed"
}
```

- Using a script block

```
0..10 | & {
    begin {
        "executes only once, before the first input object is processed"
    }
    process {
        "processes each input object: $_"
    }
    end {
        "executes only once, after the last input object is processed"
    }
}
```

[**about_Functions_Advanced_Methods**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_methods?view=powershell-7.2#begin) explain how these blocks work.

Also your code could be simplified to this:

```
$h = @{}
Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink |
    Write-Output |
    ForEach-Object { $h[$_.filename] = $_.id }
```

Or using [`Group-Object -AsHashTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3#example-7-group-objects-in-a-hash-table) as you have already found:

```
$h = Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink |
    Write-Output |
    Group-Object FileName -AsHashTable
```

`Write-Output` in this case may not be needed if the output from `Invoke-RestMethod` is already enumerated.

Comment: `Write-Output` in this case may not be needed if the output from `Invoke-RestMethod` is already enumerated."


It is, as the ouput from `Invoke-RestMethod` is paginated, so it gives me a jagged array

Comment: @GrahamReynolds so it works as expected without it?

Comment: $images = (Invoke-RestMethod @commonParams -uri "foo" -Method GET -FollowRelLink) | Write-Output | Group-Object { $_.filename } -AsHashTable - this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I assume `Write-Output` performs the same as for `ForEach-Object { $_ }` in this case? To unwrap the array of arrays.

Comment: @GrahamReynolds correct, it does. but only one level deep, it can't handle undefined levels of nest. i.e.: as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641681/15339544)